# jqGrid - How to submit non editable columns with Add Row

Tags: jqgrid

I am doing an inline add, using the inline Nav feature.  It successfully sends the data of all "edit: true" columns, but there is one other column from the grid that I need to send with the Add.  It is a hidden column and by using "editrules: { edithidden: false }, I can send the value with an edit, but not an ADD.  How to do I send hidden, non-edit columns with an ADD?

```
  { name: 'RecipKey', index: 'RecipKey', hidden: true, editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: false } },

   ...

  $("#activity-grid").jqGrid('inlineNav', '#grid-pager',
    {
        edit: true, add: true, del: true, cancel: true,
        editParams: { keys: true },
        addParams: { keys: true }
    });
```

Comment: have you tried use `extraparam`? You can pass this parameter using addRowParams . Referenc: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing

Comment: winner winner.  I was consumed with trying to get the value from the grid row, but extraparam allowed me to grab it from elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following the reference http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods:

you can pass `extraparam` on `addRowParams` when you use the method `addRow`.

example:

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('addRow',
    parameters =
    {
        addRowParams : {extraparam:{ "param1":"1","param2":"2"}}
    }
);
```